# 3rd Party API Key in cognito custom attribute JWT

Tags: jwt, cognito

I am developing an application where users need to provide an API key to a 3rd party service, our app (a serverless app on AWS with a dynamo db) then makes requests to that 3rd party service on behalf of the user.  Users are authenticated into our application through an AWS Cognito user pool.

Initially I thought about storing the API key in our db and associating it with the user, when the user makes a request to us we would retrieve the key and make the request to the 3rd party.

Another possible solution would be to store the API key as a custom attribute in cognito, when the user signs up have them enter this.  This key would then be transmitted in the id token JWT that cognito gives us after the user logs in, we could then get it and send it on without storing the key in our own DB.

Is this a good idea or a terrible idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on many factors: What is validity period of API keys? What threats you consider? What is the price of different kinds of attacks? What are usability requirements? What risks are acceptable and what are not? Etc.

In your scheme, users have no control of their API keys. There is no guarantee that API keys are used only for the purposes that users approved. There are risks that API keys will be leaked because of weaknesses in your applications (logging of API keys, providing access to user API keys to other applications or to persons that user has not authorized, etc.), and users cannot do anything to prevent it. If user provided an API key to your application and later on wants to prohibit your application to use it, there is no guarantee that your application will really do that, that there is no copy somewhere.

Better approach would be, if the 3rd party service would authenticate the user based on the API key directly, without your application, and would issue user a short-lived token, e.g. with validity of 5 minutes, and user would pass this token to your application. Then user can be sure that after the token expired your application will *guaranteed* have no access to the 3rd party API in the name of this user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer - yes I agree that it would be best if 3rd party service could allow authentication with the user directly, but it can't :( API keys are valid forever in theory - or until the user revokes them. It is an internal application so its unlikely there are any actual security risks.  My thinking was that there was an advantage having cognito store it as a custom attribute instead of us needing to manually associate the user and the key.  The JWT containing the key would be passed over https but so would the key be in a POST request if the user has to provide it at sign up ?

Comment: @Woody: 1) If this is an internal application, then why do you need a separate API key for every user? Define a *single* API for your application. It can pass user ID to the 3rd party application so that it can decide if particular request is allowed or not.

Comment: @Woody: 2) Another approach: Implement an AJAX call from client to the 3rd party API. After it obtains the response, send it from client to your application. Thus your application will obtain needed data from the 3rd party API without knowing the user API key. And you don't need to store the API key at all.

Comment: Our application is internal - i.e. only for in house users, they each have an account with the 3rd party in question which holds information specific to them. Said 3rd party app offers an API we want to use to automate a process on their behalf, each user would need their own API key so we can get at their specific information, but you have actually made me question whether this could be avoided with a single account, I think there is no way to do everything through the API that you can via the UI.

Comment: 2 would work as well I guess so is another option, there is a REST API although what we currently have uses a Python API from the back end.   Thanks again for your suggestions.